# Building Simple Web Analytics Tool

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I would like to create a simple Web Analytics tool  to be used by a small number of people running different websites as part of a project i'm doing. The reason why I am not using Google Analytics or any other free analytics tool is because I would like to learn how to build one myself. The tool just uses bars, pies and charts to display page views, clicks , referring site, traffic etc.

I've been asking around and people point me to Javascript, Python and MongoDB, the first two I know a little of. Can anyone suggest a framework for me to get started on?

Comment: You could use **google charts** to draw the bars / pie charts / graphs for you (Google Charts Gallery) :p

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely look into Keen.io if you need a place to store analytics event data and want to build your own reporting interface. They have a strong infrastructure and query tool to call up your data quickly inside a custom reporting interface.

You could also use Segment.io's collection libraries. Through segment.io you can still send data to Keen.io for your own custom use and route the same data to something like Google Analytics or Mixpanel so you have it in a pre-built system if you need it.